Is there a homogeneity issue when two gases are mixed and filled in a vessel?
When two gases (one light and one heavy) are mixed in a 36m3 vessel (mole ratio 6.5%) is there a concern about the homogeneity of the gases (101 psi)??

It is about the kinetics of mixing.

When working with gas cylinders of gas mixtures, our technicians suggested that we rolled them before use to avoid gas stratification and to ensure that the gas mixture was homogeneous. It is not that the gases are not miscible, but that the gas molecules tend to distribute themselves according to their density. But the process is very slow. Actually never used the recipe since we did not notice that effect.

All gases are completely miscible (with the caveat that under sufficient acceleration, they do separate, as in gaseous centrifugal uranium enrichment).
That said, the rate of mixing can vary. Just as warm coffee carefully poured over cold milk may form a layer lasting for minutes, as you surmise, gases might take a while to mix, too.
If helium, about 1/7 the density of air. were to be slowly introduced at the top of a container filled with sulfur hexafluoride, $\ce{SF6}$, about five times denser than air, all at room temperature, without stirring, it might take hours or days to mix to some specific homogeneity.
The rate of mixing "depends on several factors: the concentration gradient (the increase or decrease in concentration from one point to another); the amount of surface area available for diffusion; and the distance the gas particles must travel."
BTW, delayed mixing can have deadly effects, such as occurred in the Lake Nyos disaster, in which $\ce{CO2}$ erupted, and blanketed villages near the lake, killing about 1,750 people before the gas dispersed. "[T]he cloud hugged the ground and moved down the valleys... For roughly 23 kilometres (14 mi)."
